# Creating multiple shared memory segments from one process

Tags: c, shared-memory

```
void *sharedmem(int size,int q,char f){
  int shmid;
  int *segptr;
  queue *que;
  key_t key;
  char file[10];

  sprintf(file,"%c",f);
  key=ftok(file,0);
  if((shmid=shmget(key,size,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666))==-1){    
    printf("Shared memory segment exists - opening as client\n");
    if((shmid = shmget(key, size, 0)) == -1){
      perror("bad shmget");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  else
    printf("Creating new shared memory segment\n");
   if(q){
     if((que = (queue *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == NULL){
       perror("bad shmat");
       exit(1);
     }
     return que;
   }
   else {
     if((segptr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == NULL){
       perror("bad shmat");
       exit(1);
     }
     return segptr;
  }
}
```

I want to call this function 5 times, do i need to create 5 different files and make key from each?

```
$touch 1 2 3 4 5
```

then send

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 sharedmem(1,0,'1'+i);
}
```

I tried that but I get this result:

```
Shared memory segment exists - opening as client
Shared memory segment exists - opening as client
bad shmget: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're reusing the same key.  The third argument to your function is a single value - `char f`.  Did you mean `char *f` (note the `*`)?It looks like you're reusing the same key.  The third argument to your function is a single value - `char f`.  Did you mean `char *f` (note the `*`)?

Comment: sprintf make it char *

Comment: I saw that; I mean that the file name will then always be only one char - you probably want to pass in a full file name

Answer (score 0):

Just a small guess, but the ftok manual page says

> The  ftok()  function uses the identity of the file named by the given pathname (which must refer to an existing, accessible file) and the least significant 8 bits of proj_id (**which must be nonzero**) to generate a key_t type System V IPC key, suitable for use with msgget(2), semget(2), or shmget(2).

Probably the reason why you get the same token is that you're passing it zero ?

Comment: output when i pass it nonzero: Creating new shared memory segment
Shared memory segment exists - opening as client
bad shmget: No such file or directory

Comment: Hmmm... You should check that key is not -1 and you should not assume that the only reason for failure of the first shmget is that the segment already exists.

Comment: I added check that key is not -1, same output.

Comment: Use perror instead of printf for the "shared memory segment exists", then you'll know why the allocation fails.

Comment: There you go, nothing to do with your problem. Why do you have |0666, BTW ? I don't see any mode specification for the flag argument in the doc.